# PHP __call adjusting array

Tags: php

I've got this weird bug which i'm hoping someone here can help me with, or at least explain why it is happening.

I'm using the __call method ;

```
public function __call($method, $params) {
    var_dump($params);
    echo '<br/><br/>';
}
```

I call this with per example:

```
$params = array('index' => 0, 'apikey' => 'aasdf');
$client->notAFunction($params)
```

This is a non-existent method, so it will go into __call with $method = notAFunction and my array in $params.

My expected output from __call would be;

```
array(2) { ["index"]=> int(0) ["apikey"]=> string(5) "aasdf" }
```

However, what I am getting as output is;

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["index"]=> int(0) ["apikey"]=> string(5) "aasdf" } }
```

Now, I am aware of the fact that this is easily 'solved' by using $params[0] so i'm not looking for any answers like that. 
I'm looking for;

1. **Why** does this happen?
2. Can I count on this to **always** happen?
3. Is there something I can **do** that makes __call receive the original array?

Comment: Think of what would happen if you define a second array and invoke $client->notAFunction($params1, $params2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is expected functionality. Argument `$params` in the `__call` method receives the array of parameters method got.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods for description.

Comment: Thanks, now you explain it, it seems pretty logical.